# pygame is displaying a black screen whenever I run my code

Tags: python

I have done research and none of it has helped me. Whenever I run my code, pygame just displays a black screen and I don't know how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
# importing required librarys
import pygame
import sys
import chess
import math
import os 

os.chdir('/Users/stella/Desktop/comp sci NEA/ChessGame/images')

#initialise display
X = 800
Y = 800
scrn = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y))
pygame.init()

#basic colours
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREY = (128, 128, 128)
YELLOW = (204, 204, 0)
BLUE = (50, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

#initialise chess board
b = chess.Board()

#load piece images
pieces = {'p': pygame.image.load('bp.png').convert(),
          'n': pygame.image.load('bN.png').convert(),
          'b': pygame.image.load('bB.png').convert(),
          'r': pygame.image.load('bR.png').convert(),
          'q': pygame.image.load('bQ.png').convert(),
          'k': pygame.image.load('bK.png').convert(),
          'P': pygame.image.load('wp.png').convert(),
          'N': pygame.image.load('wK.png').convert(),
          'B': pygame.image.load('wB.png').convert(),
          'R': pygame.image.load('wR.png').convert(),
          'Q': pygame.image.load('wQ.png').convert(),
          'K': pygame.image.load('wK.png').convert(),
          
          }

def update(scrn,board):
    '''
    updates the screen basis the board class
    '''
    
    for i in range(64):
        piece = board.piece_at(i)
        if piece == None:
            pass
        else:
            scrn.blit(pieces[str(piece)],((i%8)*100,700-(i//8)*100))
    
    for i in range(7):
        i=i+1
        pygame.draw.line(scrn,WHITE,(0,i*100),(800,i*100))
        pygame.draw.line(scrn,WHITE,(i*100,0),(i*100,800))

    pygame.display.flip()


def main_one_agent(BOARD,agent,agent_color):
    
    '''
    for agent vs human game
    color is True = White agent
    color is False = Black agent
    '''
    
    #make background black
    scrn.fill(BLACK)
    #name window
    pygame.display.set_caption('Chess')
    
    #variable to be used later
    index_moves = []

    status = True
    while (status):
        #update screen
        update(scrn,BOARD)
        
     
        if BOARD.turn==agent_color:
            BOARD.push(agent(BOARD))
            scrn.fill(BLACK)

        else:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
         
                # if event object type is QUIT
                # then quitting the pygame
                # and program both.
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    status = False

                # if mouse clicked
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    #reset previous screen from clicks
                    scrn.fill(BLACK)
                    #get position of mouse
                    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

                    #find which square was clicked and index of it
                    square = (math.floor(pos[0]/100),math.floor(pos[1]/100))
                    index = (7-square[1])*8+(square[0])
                    
                    # if we have already highlighted moves and are making a move
                    if index in index_moves: 
                        
                        move = moves[index_moves.index(index)]
                        #print(BOARD)
                        #print(move)
                        BOARD.push(move)
                        index=None
                        index_moves = []
                        
                    # show possible moves
                    else:
                        
                        piece = BOARD.piece_at(index)
                        
                        if piece == None:
                            
                            pass
                        else:

                            all_moves = list(BOARD.legal_moves)
                            moves = []
                            for m in all_moves:
                                if m.from_square == index:
                                    
                                    moves.append(m)

                                    t = m.to_square

                                    TX1 = 100*(t%8)
                                    TY1 = 100*(7-t//8)

                                    
                                    pygame.draw.rect(scrn,BLUE,pygame.Rect(TX1,TY1,100,100),5)
                            #print(moves)
                            index_moves = [a.to_square for a in moves]
     
    # deactivates the pygame library
        if BOARD.outcome() != None:
            print(BOARD.outcome())
            status = False
            print(BOARD)


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

When I run it, all that is displayed is a black screen. No errors are called.
Some of the answers I found suggested indentation but I don't know where that would be as I am fairly new to coding.

Comment: Where do you call `main_one_agent`?

Comment: I don't know, I am using a tutorial and it doesn't say.

Comment: Then go back to your tutorial. Pleas learn the basics an consider [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Without calling a function, the code in the function will not be executed.